# How to get hold of the percentag value?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

this is my code to get the percentage from this particular website, but I always get errors and with the new version of selenium I’m really overwhelmed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Development/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://metf.finance/#/dashboard")
time.sleep(5)
percentage = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='bond-discounts a')
print(percentage.text)

driver.quit()
```

This is the Error I get

```
File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\METF ALARM\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    percentage = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='bond-discounts a')
  File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\METF ALARM\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1248, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\METF ALARM\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\METF ALARM\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"bond-discounts a"}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Or where do look in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 percentages there.
You can get all the 3 values as following

```py
driver.get("https://metf.finance/#/dashboard")
time.sleep(5)
percentages = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bond-discounts']//span")
for percentage in percentages:
    print(percentage.text)
```

You also should not use hardcoded pauses like `time.sleep(5)`, Expected Conditions explicit waits should be used instead